# Facebook Ads API Invalid Scopes: ads_management

Tags: facebook-ads-api

We're using an app that has access to the Marketing API (basic access). We've migrated everything to v2.2 a while ago.
Today we noticed that when logging in or reauthorising the application we see the message: `Invalid Scopes: ads_management.`

We've been using the permission for a while now and I can't find anything about changes to it in any of the latest upgrades. Are we missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the app has read/write access, and you didn't request insights only access or something? The only reason i can think of that an app can't request ads_management but could before is if it had read/write access in Basic but applied for Insights access at Standard level instead

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I have confirmed that we have Ads Management Basic Access, which includes read and write access. We've been using the ads_management permission for many months until we couldn't anymore since the end of last week. Absolutely nothing has changed.

Comment: If you're sure your app has Basic or Standard access shown in the Status & Review tab of the app settings, please file a bug report showing repro steps for the Login dialog not allowing you to request ads_management: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1111027455590700/

Comment: @Igy See link above. It seems we have been silently downgraded or something? We do still see Basic access in the Status & Review tab but in the API Explorer, when selecting the app, we also can't select the ads_management permission anymore. For testing purposes we used the explorer at the beginning of the week and I know for certain that we could select it then.

Comment: @Nyveria have you found a solution? We recently discovered the same issue.

Comment: Hi @AlexPliutau, sorry, only just saw your comment. Their fix resolved our issue, so perhaps it broke again. I recommend searching for similar issues and otherwise filing it as a bug on their bugs platform: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They admitted this was a bug on their side resulting in apps with Basic access only having read access. They will push a fix for it today. When its live and it indeed fixes the problem I'll mark this as the answer.