# How to get users' FB Ad Account Id via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get my own ad account id via a curl requests to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id%2Cname%2Cadaccounts&access_token=
```

We have Ads Management Basic Access permissions from Facebook.

I have also tried https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/

Both get the same error.

```
{ error: 
   { message: '(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.',
     type: 'OAuthException',
     code: 3,
     fbtrace_id: 'HiXZVS8UeI8' } }
```

What is the endpoint to get user Ad accounts? What permissions do I need?

Answer (score 0):

The [page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/) you link to lists

> Managing advertisements requires an access token with the extended
>   permission for ads_management

You can test in the [Graph API Console](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) when you generate a new token

Comment: We have the permissions! Also we have tried it on graph API and it works for our own accounts. But when we grab a user key from staging we notice the error above. Or if we ask a user to give us their sign in to try it directly, it shows the error in spite of having the permissions.

Comment: How were those tokens generated?

Comment: They are generated using Node Passport or Nodejs Everyauth. I am using the application public and private keys. Moreover, if it was a key or setting error the keys that I generated for myself should also not work.

Comment: Looks like we are having this issue. I will mark an answer when they reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072877/facebook-ads-api-invalid-scopes-ads-management